# How I could use the OpenX API through ajax to increment the click counts of a banner?

Tags: javascript, ajax, openx

I have a lot of troubles with flashs banners without the clicktag. So, I decided to look for some trick to simulate them. I thougth that maybe, if a put the banner inside a div, and I use JavaScript to capture the "click event", of the div, I could simulate the click but I don't know how send this information to my AdServer (OpenX), so it could count the clicks.

How I could update, through ajax, usign the OpenX API, the click counter of a banner

Answer (score 1):

See below:

"server"/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?bannerid="your banner id"&zoneid="your zone id"

Example: localhost/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?bannerid=1&zoneid=1